# ¿Como puedo leer un archivo en CSV en C++?

Tags: c++

```
void CPila::insertarElemento(int ele){
    if(esPilaLlena()==1)
       cout<<"Imposible insertar"<<endl;
    else
    {
        tope=tope+1;
        arreglo[tope]=ele;
    };
 }
int main(){

}
```

Tengo en mi excel los datos datos que quiero agregar a mi pila ¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Un CSV es un archivo de texto, en el que en cada línea tienes una fila de la hoja de cálculo. Si hay varias columnas, éstas estarán separadas por `;` dentro de cada línea (o quizás por `,` deberías mirarlo). Por tanto se leen como cualquier otro fichero de texto orientado a líneas, y en tu ejemplo en que solo hay una columna más fácil aún porque no tienes ni que dividir cada línea por el carácter separador.

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada?